# UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment when variable has both local and global scope

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a >1000 line code which has something similar to this block of code.

```
import random
def assignment():
    global a
    a=10

def confusion():
    t=random.randint(0,50)
    if(t==10):
        a = 5
        return a
    assignment()
    # global a #Can be fixed like this
    print a

confusion()
```

I get the following error when t != 10

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UnboundLocalVariable.py", line 15, in <module>
    confusion()
  File "UnboundLocalVariable.py", line 13, in confusion
    print (a)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Using Python 3.5.2
Now I understand why it should always give an error whenever t != 10 but the problem is it gives error rarely. Any insights on what can be the reason for not failing when will be appreciated.

Comment: The presence of an assignment to `a` inside `confusion()` makes it a local variable by default, unrelated to the global `a`.  Whether or not that assignment actually gets executed on a given call to the function does not change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
import random
def assignment():
    global a
    a=10

def confusion():
    global a
    t=random.randint(0,50)
    if(t==10):
        a = 5
        return a
    assignment() 
    print a

confusion()
```

The error you faced was because the "a" param wasn't assigned to any value.
Just note that the assignment() method is not the best practice in this case.

Comment: Hi Leo, Thanks for the response. However, my question was different. Here in assignment function, you can see that the scope of "a" is defined as global.

Comment: The global definition is for calling the same param from difference scopes so if you reach the same value in confusion function you need to call global "a" inside of it as I edited. But note the it is not a best practice to use.